# HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable. .Net Core Website

Tags: c#, .net, iis, hosting, web-deployment

I've uploaded my .Net Core 1.1 Web Application to my new host a few days ago and have been receiving the error: HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable

This is due to the ISS App Pool turning itself off every time I switch it on or restart it.

Reading other articles about this problem suggest it is to do with Identity on the App Pool, which I cannot change through this host and have been told that this isn't the problem.

The problem I can't solve is why:
I am currently running my application off my local IIS with no such problem, it runs great. I also deployed my Application to Azure as a test a couple of weeks ago and it worked great too.

I've raised a ticket with the web host and have been told it is a problem with my code that needs resolving, but I have no idea where to look first? How is best to tackle this problem?

[image: Message from Web Host support]

Comment: Have you tried a simple hello world type one?

Comment: I haven't. I'll try that now

Comment: always worth a try start with something real stupidly simple and then you can narrow it down

Comment: @BugFinder fair point. I've tried to deploy the standard .net core web project to it and I had the same issues. So I deleted everything from the hhtpdocs and uploaded a static.html to find I still get the same issue. I've recontacted the host provider explaining.

Comment: It's now fixed. The hosting company remade the service and it works fine now.

Comment: But of course wasnt anything their end !!!